# Printing multiple tables using nested for loops in PHP

Tags: php

I am new to PHP. I am having some issues being able to print multiple tables using a nested for loop. So with the current code I have a nested for loop that only prints out 1 table which is the same as what I get when I take the outer for loop out. I have some hard-coded data in the array and I want the the nested for loop to be able to print out 4 of the same tables. For some reason this is not working based on what I have and I can't seem to figure out why it is not.

Eventually instead of having hard-coded data we will be pulling from a DB. We will have to pull from one database which needs the populate the order correctly based on conference and based on my current logic I wanted to know if this was still a possibility based on the way I am directing myself. I am really trying to figure this out and would appreciate an explanation of why it was not working. Thank you all in advance!

PHP Code:

```
<?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>User selection page</title>
    </head>


    <?php
        /*
        Version 1.1: Instead of printing the teams in different cells we are going to print the 
        games in one row and we select the game itself to see if an upset will occur.
        */  

        require_once('Conference.php'); 

        for ($i = 0; $i<4; $i++)
        {       
            $loadGameClass = new Conference();
            $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array("(1)Gonzaga vs (16)Southern U", "(8)Pittsburgh vs (9)Wichita St", "(5)Wisconsin vs (12)Ole Miss", "(4)Kansas st vs (13)Boise St", "(6)Arizona vs (11)Belmont", "(3)New Mexico vs (14) Harvard", "(7)Notre Dame vs (10)Iowa St", "(2)Ohio St vs (15) Iona"));
            $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();

            echo '<table border="1">';

            for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++) 
            {
                $highSeed = $teams[$i];
                echo '<tr><td>'.$highSeed.'</td><tr>';
            }

            echo '</table>';
            echo "\n";
        }
    ?>

    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You use `$i` in the inner and the outer loop. Just replace the inner loop iterator e.g. by `$j` and your code is working.

Comment: Thank you! That worked and I probably scanned the code 100 times, but I just didn't notice that small little bug

Answer (score 0):

This code should work fine for you:

```
<?php print( '<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8"?>') ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>User selection page</title>
    </head>
<body>
<?php
//added the php in the body tag because you can't add content between </head> and <body>
            /*
        Version 1.1: Instead of printing the teams in different cells we are going to print the 
        games in one row and we select the game itself to see if an upset will occur.
        */  

        require_once('Conference.php'); 

        for ($i = 0; $i<4; $i++)
        {       
            $loadGameClass = new Conference();
            $loadGameClass->loadTeams(array("(1)Gonzaga vs (16)Southern U", "(8)Pittsburgh vs (9)Wichita St", "(5)Wisconsin vs (12)Ole Miss", "(4)Kansas st vs (13)Boise St", "(6)Arizona vs (11)Belmont", "(3)New Mexico vs (14) Harvard", "(7)Notre Dame vs (10)Iowa St", "(2)Ohio St vs (15) Iona"));
            $teams = $loadGameClass->getTeams();

            echo '<table border="1">';

            for ($x = 0; $x < 8; $x++) //replaced $i by $x
            {
                $highSeed = $teams[$x];//replaced $i by $x
                echo '<tr><td>'.$highSeed.'</td><tr>';
            }

            echo '</table>';
            echo "\n";
        }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Your code wasn't working because you've used the same variable name for outer and inner loop. Outer loop's $i is overwritten by the second loop each time. Therefore you didn't get the right table.

If I understand it right you want to print the results in the table from a database and order it by most conferenced item? You've to replace $loadGameClass to $teams and replace it for this:

```
$loadGame = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM teams ORDER BY most_conferenced ASC');
```

and you're inner loop should be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($loadGame)){
    print '<tr><td>'.$row['match_text'].'</td></tr>';
}
```

And your database will looks like this:

```
Teams:
id:int primary key ai
match_text:string
conferenced:int
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am not quite sure how your logic for pulling the database is working. Here is a link http://espn.go.com/mens-college-basketball/tournament/bracket
As you can see there are 4 conferences. The outer most games is what I am working with right now. I want to print each conference in a table which is 8 games. We have to pull the data correctly and place them in order from top to bottom just how it looks in the bracket in a table for each conference. I just want to see if this is logically possible with PHP since I have never done anything with MySQL and PHP before.